# Какой тип данных выбрать в БД для хранения ссылки на картинку?

Tags: mysql, sql

Какой тип данных выбрать в БД для хранения ссылки на картинку? И как правильно надо делать?

Comment: Что-то мне подсказывает, что в бд лучше хранить чисто имя с расширением.. А пути будут прописаны в настройках приложения. Ведь пути могут поменяться и тогда все ссылки у вас будут битые

Answer (score 1):

Лучше храни id в `int`, расширение в `tinytext`, изображения пусть будут в одном каталоге, называться `[id].[расширение]`.